# How to map specializations array with JSON Vue/vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

```
Hello guys,
```

// I have one problem with map in Vue.js, how can i map array specializations ? How to display a whole array in 1 div. I would like to make a filter later.

```
 Below it's my JSON file

My JSON file 

{
  "workers": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Karolina Water",
       "email":"Karolina.water@gmail.com",
       "specializations": [
        {
          "code": "net",
          "name": ".NET"
        },
        {
          "code": "react",
          "name": "React JS"
        }
      ]
    },  {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Marcelina Wart",
       "email":"Marcelina.wart@gmail.com",
       "specializations": [
        {
          "code": "net",
          "name": ".NET"
        }
      ]
    },
    
  ]
}
```

Below it's my component,

```
          <tr v-for="worker in workers" :key="worker.id">
            <th scope="row">{{ worker.id }}</th>   // 
            <td>{{ worker.name }}</td>          // 
            <td>{{worker.specializations[0].name}} </td>  //- but i have only 1 value from the array.
            <td>go to projects ➡</td>
          </tr>
 many thanks  for your help !
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a nested v-for.

See it here in action: [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<template>
  <table border>
    <tr v-for="worker in workers" :key="worker.id">
      <th scope="row">{{ worker.id }}</th>
      <td>{{ worker.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <div v-for="spec in worker.specializations">
          {{spec.code}} - {{spec.name}}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      workers: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Karolina Water",
          email: "Karolina.water@gmail.com",
          specializations: [
            {
              code: "net",
              name: ".NET",
            },
            {
              code: "react",
              name: "React JS",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Marcelina Wart",
          email: "Marcelina.wart@gmail.com",
          specializations: [
            {
              code: "net",
              name: ".NET",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
});
</script>
```